# Error uploading aab to Google Play: Android Studio Iguana

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

In the latest version: Android Studio Iguana no option to create aab file

The application was made Flutter.

What I did:

1. opened the project from the Android folder
   From the menu, I selected:

- Biuld -> General Signed Bundle / APK
- APK and click Next

Click "Create New"

```
Key store path: create a folder and enter any key name.
Enter password: mypassword
Enter Alias: key
Enter password: mypassword
Set 50 years
Enter name
Organizational unit: type Android development team
Organization type company name
City: type Warsaw
State or Province: Poland
Country Code: my postal code
```

Click Next, Next...
Finally, select release and debug

Copy the created key and paste it into android/app

Edit: android/gradle.properties

```
storeFile_=key.jks
keyAlias_=key
storePassword_=mypassword
keyPassword_=mypassword
```

Click: Build -> Re-build

Close Android Studio

Right-click on the flutter folder and open it in the terminal.
I typed flutter build appbundle

The aab file was created.

In Google Console, I add a new application and upload the aab file there.

After a while I get an error message:
The uploaded APK file or Android app package was signed in debug mode. You need to sign it in final mode

Please help, what did I do wrong?

In the past, I created the aab file directly in Android Studio by checking the option:
Export encrypted key for enrolling published apps in Google Play App Signing

But this is no longer present in the latest version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate signed app bundle using **Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/APK** in Android Studio.

Error:  The uploaded APK file or Android app package was signed in debug mode. You need to sign it in final mode.

At the last step of the above flow. Make sure you select **release** build variant not a debug.

Also you don't need to create Key store every time you generate a signed bundle. You need to use the **same Key store file** which you've used to upload the first release on Google play in order to publish the updates to the app.

Check the detailed documentation here.
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing

Also **don't put your release Key store file or passwords in project**. Placing it in the project makes it accessible to anyone who gains access to your code repository, posing a security risk.

Comment: This guide is out of date. The latest version of Android Studio lacks this:
https://i.im.ge/2024/03/18/RCSEEr.Zrzut-ekranu-2024-03-18-092603.png

Comment: From this: android/gradle.properties remove it completely? `storeFile_=key.jks
keyAlias_=key
storePassword_=mypassword
keyPassword_=mypassword`

Comment: Exporting encrypted keys is deprecated in the latest version. Check the NOTE in the same documentation. You don't need that to generate a signed bundle.

Comment: In order to push an update , you need your existing Key store file which you've generated at the first.